# AngularJS onYoutubeIframeAPIReady only works after refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have an AngularJS application where i'm working with embedded youtube videos, but I'm struggling with a specific error for a while now. There are some posts about it here on Stackoverflow, but I can't get it solved.

When I open the page and press the play 'button' (or div), the video and the custom mediaplayer are shown and working, but when I go back- and forwards to another page, the function will not be called again and shows nothing.

**The html (the video will be shown here):**

```
<div id="video-placeholder">

</div>
```

and

**The button which triggers the function in the controller:**

```
<div class="title-artist-button" ng-click="openYoutubeLink(upload.uploadUrl,upload.startSec,upload.endSec)">
    <div id="title-artist">

    </div>
</div>
```

**So this function:**

```
$scope.openYoutubeLink = function (uploadUrl, startSec, endSec) {

    $('#video-placeholder').show();
    $('.mediaplayer').fadeIn(800);
    $('.glyphicon-play').hide();
    $('.glyphicon-pause').show();
    player.playVideo();
    getTrackInfo(uploadUrl, startSec, endSec);
    initialize();
};

function getTrackInfo (uploadUrl, startSec, endSec) {
    player.loadVideoById({videoId:uploadUrl, startSeconds:startSec, endSeconds:endSec});
};
```

**And ofcourse the YoutubeApi function:**

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
    player = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        playerVars: {
            color: 'white',
            enablejsapi:1,
            showinfo:0,
            rel:0,
            iv_load_policy:3,
            controls:0,
            autoplay:0
        },
        events: {
            onReady: initialize,
            onReady: getTrackInfo,
            onReady: getTitle
        }
    });
}
```

So when I refresh, it gives no errors, but when I move back- and forward, there is this console error:

```
angular.js:13294 TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null
at X.g.K (https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflQQmM0D/www-    widgetapi.js:98:332)
at S (https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflQQmM0D/www-widgetapi.js:90:99)
at X.(anonymous function).Nb.(anonymous function) [as playVideo] (https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflQQmM0D/www-widgetapi.js:131:124)
at Scope.$scope.openYoutubeLink (http://127.0.0.1:50643/js/controllers/profileController.js:53:10)
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.js:14138:15), <anonymous>:4:716)
at expensiveCheckFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.js:15151:18)
at callback (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.js:24674:17)
at Scope.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.js:16895:28)
at Scope.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.js:16995:25)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.js:24679:23)
```

I know it is a lot of stuff, but I tried to be as clear as possible. Does someone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: A [ticket](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube-api-gdata/bThZuUg51qg/UxGHP19-bWIJ) in the YouTube public issue tracker indicates that the DOM may still be null when the script was called. Try to set the container first before triggering the script and hopefully that will solve the issue.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm currently facing the same issue.

Comment: No, I solved it a bit different. Instead of having the video-placeholder on every html-page separately, I put it in the index with ng-include (because I'm using Angular) and than tweaked it with ng-show. It worked for my app, but I didn't manage to find a good solution to the exact problem above.